# Windows Vista Won't Boot Dual Boot

Tags: windows, boot, windows-vista

Recently I tried to dual-boot my Windows Vista laptop.

I stupidly moved the Windows partition a tiny bit to the right.
Now the Windows bootloader is pointing to an empty part of the disk.

How can I fix the bootloader to point at the correct place?

Answer (score 1):

I did that before with windows 7 and tried this - reinstalling windows 7 and when given the choice to 'upgrade' or 'install fresh' i told it to do it as an upgrade. It found the right partition and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix BCD with a simple command from recovery/installation DVD/USB.

**bcdedit /store c:\boot\bcd /set {GUID} device partition=d:**

- c: is where boot files are (active partition)
- d: is where your Windows is installed

c: and d: could be the same partition, exact mapping you can get using "diskpart.exe" (list volumes)

- {GUID} is the loader id

to obtain {GUID} use "bcdedit /store c:\boot\bcd" (c: is active partition), this command lists boot manager and loaders